# How to pass PWCHAR to C++ dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I have an dll written in C++, and I want to call it from C#. The function outputs outputChar and deadChar, the deadChar variable is also read by the C++ function.

I tried to call function from C# in different ways, but all time I got AccessViolationException: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

C++ dll:

```
extern "C" _declspec (dllexport) int convertVirtualKeyToWChar(int virtualKey, PWCHAR outputChar, PWCHAR deadChar);
```

C# code 1:

```
[DllImport("keylib.dll")]
static extern int convertVirtualKeyToWChar(int virtualKey,
               StringBuilder output,
               StringBuilder deadchar);
```

C# code 2:

```
static extern int convertVirtualKeyToWChar(int virtualKey,
           out char output,
           ref char deadchar);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note:*  The two `PWCHAR` arguments to your function `convertVirtualKeyToWChar` are ambiguous.  They could be pointers to a single `WCHAR` or pointers to a`WCHAR` string.  Given the name of the function and arguments, this answer assumes they are pointers to a single `WCHAR`.

You want to use the following:

> ```
> [DllImport("keylib.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
> static extern int convertVirtualKeyToWChar( int virtualKey,
>        out char output,
>        ref char deadchar );
> ```

Your crash is caused by two reasons:  `DllImport` defaults to the ANSI character set and StdCall calling convention.  Your C++ DLL does not specify any calling convention, so it will default to CDecl.

See [DllImportAttribute.CallingConvention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention.aspx) and [DllImportAttribute.CharSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset.aspx)

Comment: Technically, CharSet is for how the marshaller handles strings.  A ref/out char will marshal as wchar_t* regardless of CharSet.

Comment: @peter The CharSet setting does affect the marshaling on a single char.  I made a test program to verify.  If I have a C# `char` and set the value to `'\x1042'`, the C++ function will receive the same value for Unicode CharSet, but `\x3F` if the CharSet is Ansi or unspecified.

Comment: You are indeed correct.  I thought the marshaller wouldn't bother for a single character, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

This is a stab in the dark, so *caveat emptor*...

```
static extern int convertVirtualKeyToWChar(int virtualKey,
                                           char[] output,
                                           char[] deadchar);
```

Pass a single-element array to each `char[]` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (bearing in mind that if an exception is thrown between Alloc and Free you will leak memory, so build some error handling in):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr pout = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(2);
        IntPtr pdead = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(2);

        int ret = convertVirtualKeyToWChar(1, pout, pdead);
        char output = (char)Marshal.ReadInt16(pout);
        char dead = (char)Marshal.ReadInt16(pdead);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pout);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pdead);
    }

    static extern int convertVirtualKeyToWChar(int virtualKey,
       IntPtr output,
       IntPtr deadchar);
```